# imutils.imlist openCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am currently using OPENCV 3.1 version

I am facing error in using imutils.imlist(dir)
error 
 AttributeError: module 'imutils' has no attribute 'imlist'

please suggest some other attribute which can be used instead of imlist
or tell what imlist does exaclty

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an `imlist` attribute in the `imutils` module. Perhaps describe what you're trying to do instead? :-)

Comment: Actually I am trying to run a code from net
 https://learndeltax.blogspot.in/2016/04/image-classification-using.html

in here he used imlist , I am also trying to figure out what he is trying to do with that imlist attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the blog post completely, you will realize that the blogger wasn't using the pip package imutils. He was using his own custom file which he imported and the name of the custom file is imutils, which is present on [github](https://github.com/manojkiraneda/Machine-Perception/blob/6142e09aed776da8ad71473747de4db8865f2b1c/Image%20Classification(ML)/code%20(kNN)/import%20files%20for%20python/imutils.py).

As of 19 March, 2017, the function you are looking for is:

```
def imlist(path):
    """
    The function imlist returns all the names of the files in 
    the directory path supplied as argument to the function.
    """
    return [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
```

That being said, IIUC, this function assumes that all files inside the given directory are images. Instead of that, the `imutils` package which you are using, has a function of it's own, called [`list_images`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#recursively-listing-paths-to-images) which provides similar functionality (it's recursive). You can use it like this:

```
from imutils import paths

list(paths.list_images('/path/to/dir/containing/images'))
```